# cocoapods multiple target results in redefinition

Tags: cocoapods, cocoapods-1.2

I am experiencing a lot of 'Redefinition' and 'has a previous declaration' errors from updating my Podfile recently. I have multiple targets and I am sharing a few pods between them all. I was previously using 0.XX and have recently updated to 1.2 and have been trying to keep up with Podfile standards.

I am updating my Podfile from what it was recently:

```
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

    platform :ios, '8.0'

    link_with 'Target1', 'Target2', 'Target3', 'Target4', 'Target5', 'Target6'

    pod 'RestKit', '0.24.0'

    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '0.9'

    pod 'MHVideoPhotoGallery', '1.6'
```

to what is expected in Cocoa Pods 1.2:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '8.0'


def core_pods

    pod 'RestKit', '0.26.0'

    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '0.9'

    pod 'MHVideoPhotoGallery', '1.6'

    pod 'FLKAutoLayout', '1.0.0'

    pod 'IGListKit', '~> 2.0.0'

end


abstract_target 'core' do

    core_pods


    target 'Target1'
    target 'Target2'
    target 'Target3'
    target 'Target4'
    target 'Target5'
    target 'Target6'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issues were caused because of an incorrect search path added to Library Search Paths referencing the `/DerivedData/` folder as well as an added Other Linker Flag of `-all_load`.